# <> not equal to function doesn't work appropriately to filter records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a business requirement where I need to alter the SSRS report based on some additional filtering. I have a field name as ProductShortName where they don't want records where Product name is 'BLOC', 'Small Business Visa', Product name starting with 'WOW' and Product name ending with 'Review'.

This is the original where condition:

```
       WHERE ( A.AppDetailSavePointID = 0) AND (B.QueueID = 1) 
              AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
              AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
              OR  (A.AppDetailSavePointID = 0) 
              AND  ((B.QueueID = - 25) OR (B.QueueID = - 80)) 
              AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
              AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
              OR  (A.AppDetailSavePointID = 0) 
              AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
              AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
              AND (LEFT(C.QueueName, 2) = 'LC')
```

I added additional filtering to meet the criteria:

```
 WHERE (A.AppDetailSavePointID = 0) 
        AND ((A.ProductShortName <> 'BLOC') 
        AND (A.ProductShortName <> 'Small Business Visa') 
        AND NOT (A.ProductShortName LIKE 'WOW%') 
        AND NOT (A.ProductShortName LIKE '%Review')) 
        AND (B.QueueID = 1) 
        AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
        AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
        OR (A.AppDetailSavePointID = 0) 
        AND ((B.QueueID = - 25) OR (B.QueueID = - 80)) 
        AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
        AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
        AND ((A.ProductShortName <> 'BLOC') 
        AND (A.ProductShortName <> 'Small Business Visa') 
        AND NOT (A.ProductShortName LIKE 'WOW%') 
        AND NOT (A.ProductShortName LIKE '%Review')) 
        AND (A.AppDetailSavePointID = 0) 
        AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
        AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
        AND (LEFT(C.QueueName, 2) = 'LC') 
        AND ((A.ProductShortName <> 'BLOC') 
        AND (A.ProductShortName <> 'Small Business Visa') 
        AND NOT (A.ProductShortName LIKE 'WOW%') 
        AND NOT (A.ProductShortName LIKE '%Review'))
```

While this removes the products but it additionally removes few more products. I don't understand how? Can anyone please suggest an appropriate where condition?

Comment: Can you show some sample data?  There isn't nearly enough information here to really help much.

Comment: I think you're missing some parentheses around your groups of criteria. Your `AND`s and `OR`s aren't working together the way you may think they are.

Comment: Right now if AppDetailSavePointID = 0, then none of the other conditions will matter.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @TabAlleman: No, Along with AppDetailsavePointID = 0, I also want to filter the records where the product Name is not qual to BLOC, Small Business Visa, Product stating with WOW and Product ending with Review. Additionally, DesicionStatusName should not be Cancelled and withdrawn

Comment: Are any of your columns nullable? A null value in one of the compared columns can short-circuit the entire condition.

Comment: Also what do your joins look like? Are all of these columns in a single table? (You should use table aliases and prefix the columns with them - this helps you and us.)

Comment: Ok, well in your second WHERE clause, you have " (AppDetailSavePointID = 0)" on three different lines, which makes no sense unless you start nesting parenthesis.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Its a good point, but the columns which i am filtering are not nullable.

Comment: My guess is that you messed up the AND and OR conditions. See Pradeep Kumar's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to read if you deassociate the universal predicates.

`(X and Y) or (X and Z) == X and (Y or Z)`

This yields:

```
WHERE (A.ProductShortName NOT LIKE 'WOW%')
  AND (A.ProductShortName NOT LIKE '%Review')
  AND (A.ProductShortName <> 'Small Business Visa')
  AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled')
  AND (A.DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn')
  AND (A.AppDetailSavePointID = 0)
  AND (   QueueID = 1
       OR QueueID = -25
       OR QueueID = -80
       OR LEFT(C.QueueName, 2) = 'LC'
      )
```

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid mixing AND and OR conditions without bracketing them properly.
If you are mixing ANDs and ORs then put brackets to resolve the confusions. If you don't do that, the results would be unexpected.

For example, in your query, if AppDetailSavePointID = 0 then all other conditions become invalid/irrelevent. I'm sure this not what you want.

```
   WHERE (AppDetailSavePointID = 0) AND (QueueID = 1) 
          AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
          AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
          OR  (AppDetailSavePointID = 0) 
          AND  ((QueueID = - 25) OR (QueueID = - 80)) 
          AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
          AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
          OR  (AppDetailSavePointID = 0) 
          AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
          AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
          AND (LEFT(QueueName, 2) = 'LC')
```

**EDIT**

You should take either AND or OR as the major part, but not a mixture of AND and OR (without brackets). You can use additonal brackets to specify the other.

e.g.

Assuming  a,b,c,d,e,f... are conditions of type `Field op value` (e.g. AppDetailSavePointID = 0, DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled' etc.).

You should not do this:

```
-- don't do this.
WHERE a
AND b
OR c
AND d 
OR e
AND f 
OR g
```

You can do either of these two things:

```
-- this is ok.
WHERE a
AND b
AND c
AND (d OR e)
AND (f OR g)
```

Or,

```
-- this is ok.
WHERE a
OR b
OR c
OR (d AND e)
OR (f AND g)
```

Comment: In addtion to the incorrect use of and/or, is it possible that some of the tables refernenced are part of a left join?

Comment: _For example, in your query, if AppDetailSavePointID = 0 then all other conditions become invalid/irrelevent. I'm sure this not what you want._ - AppDetailSavePointID is not the primary key. It just results into the most recent transaction. The values in this column are in the range 0 - 1. O being the most recent transaction and 3 the oldest. I suppose, I should have mentioned this as I see, it created lot of confusion. Thank you for your efforts though.

Comment: Irrespective of what datatype the field is, what data it holds, or whether it is primary key or not, that statement in my answer still holds true. You would need to do proper bracketing of conditions to resolve the confusion. I edited my answer to provide a detailed explanation of how it should be done. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If the original condition was working I would just add to it. Try the following:

```
WHERE 
    (AppDetailSavePointID = 0) AND (QueueID = 1) 
    AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
    AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
    OR  (AppDetailSavePointID = 0) 
    AND  ((QueueID = - 25) OR (QueueID = - 80)) 
    AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
    AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
    OR  (AppDetailSavePointID = 0) 
    AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Cancelled') 
    AND (DecisionStatusName <> N'Withdrawn') 
    AND (LEFT(QueueName, 2) = 'LC')
    AND NOT (
        ProductShortName IN ('BLOC', 'Small Business Visa')
        OR ProductShortName LIKE 'WOW%'
        OR ProductShortName LIKE '%Review'
    )
```